# Amazon Alexa Account Linking Does Not Present The Authorization Link on LinkAccount Card

Tags: oauth, alexa-skills-kit

Having gone through an endless amount of materials on the topic, would appreciate help here please:

I am setting up OAuth 2.0 account linking from an Amazon Alexa "skill" to an external service. The skill successfully identifies the lack of an access token and displays a LinkAccount card to the user. Problem is: the card contains no link to the authorization page.

Respective Authorization URI definitely is provided in the skill's account linking settings.

Intent's code:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {

canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
},

handle(handlerInput) {
    const accessToken = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken;

    if (accessToken == undefined){
        const speechText = "Please use the Alexa app to link your Amazon account to the external account" 

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .withLinkAccountCard()
            .getResponse();

    } else {
        const speechText = 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say hello!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
},
```

};

JSON Output:

```
{
"body": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "SSML",
            "ssml": "<speak>Please use the Alexa app to link your Amazon account to the external account</speak>"
        },
        "card": {
            "type": "LinkAccount"
        }
    },
    "sessionAttributes": {},
    "userAgent": "ask-node/2.0.7 Node/v6.10.3"
}
```

}

I am using Amazon developer console simulator and an iOS Alexa app for testing (no physical device).

Thank you.

Comment: There is known bug in Alexa Android app that doesn't show the  login page even if the user click "Link Account" on the card presented. Don't know about IOS app. Another alternative is to check it in web version of the app at alexa.amazon.com.
Also, you can disable and renable the skill to goto login page and check if everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Cicil. It still did not work out, perhaps I would try again fresh later.

Comment: Did you try disabling and re enabliy the skill?. Is it redirecting to the login page that time.

Comment: I certainly tried writing that skill as a totally new one several times over. What would disabling and reenabling mean? Anyways, thank you.